# Discord.js Error Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I saw this condition in an Ultrax video, however the code is not working, it should send a welcome image when someone new enters the server, can someone help me fix the code?

Code:

````
registerFont('./font/OpenSans-Bold.ttf', { family: 'Open Sans' })
const canvas = createCanvas(500, 500)
const Canvas = require('canvas');

var welcomeCanvas = {};
welcomeCanvas.create = Canvas.createCanvas(1024, 500)
welcomeCanvas.context = welcomeCanvas.create.getContext('2d')
welcomeCanvas.context.font = '72px OpenSans-Bold';
welcomeCanvas.context.fillStyle = '#ffffff';

Canvas.loadImage("./img/Teste.png").then(async (img) => {
welcomeCanvas.context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 1024, 500)
welcomeCanvas.context.fillText("Testando boas vindas", 360, 360);
welcomeCanvas.context.beginPath();
welcomeCanvas.context.arc(512, 166, 128, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
welcomeCanvas.context.stroke()
welcomeCanvas.context.fill()
})

require('ultrax').inviteLogger(client)

client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
const welcomechannel = Client.channels.cache.get('794293128600879125')
let canvas = welcomeCanvas;
canvas.context.font = '42px OpenSans-Bold';
canvas.context.textAling = 'center';
canvas.context.fillText(member.user.tag.toUpperCase(), 512, 410)
canvas.context.font = '32px OpenSans-Bold';
canvas.context.fillText(Você é o ${member.guild.memberCount} Tenno em nosso servidor, 512, 455)
canvas.context.beginPath()
canvas.context.arc(512, 166, 119, 0, Math.PI * 2, true)
canvas.context.closePath()
canvas.context.clip()
await Canvas.loadImage(member.user.displayAvatarURL({format: 'png', size: 1024}))
.then(img => {
canvas.context.drawImage(img, 393, 47, 238, 238);
})
let atta = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.create.toBuffer(), Bem vindo ${member.id}.png)
try {
welcomechannel.send(Olá Tenno ${member}, bem vindo ao ${member.guild.name}!, atta)
} catch (error) {
console.log(error)
}
});```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the issue was that you needed to load Canvas before using some of the functions in your code. I have repaired your code below. If that doesn't fix the issue, check whether your font file is really in the directory that you're trying to load it from. If you're using a handler of some sort, that could change the directory (though it doesn't look that way).

```js
const Canvas = require('canvas');
const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(500, 500)
Canvas.registerFont('./font/OpenSans-Bold.ttf', { family: 'Open Sans' })

var welcomeCanvas = {};
welcomeCanvas.create = Canvas.createCanvas(1024, 500)
welcomeCanvas.context = welcomeCanvas.create.getContext('2d')
welcomeCanvas.context.font = '72px OpenSans-Bold';
welcomeCanvas.context.fillStyle = '#ffffff';

Canvas.loadImage("./img/Teste.png").then(async (img) => {
    welcomeCanvas.context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 1024, 500)
    welcomeCanvas.context.fillText("Testando boas vindas", 360, 360);
    welcomeCanvas.context.beginPath();
    welcomeCanvas.context.arc(512, 166, 128, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    welcomeCanvas.context.stroke()
    welcomeCanvas.context.fill()
})

require('ultrax').inviteLogger(client)

client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    const welcomechannel = client.channels.cache.get('794293128600879125')
    let canvas = welcomeCanvas;
    canvas.context.font = '42px OpenSans-Bold';
    canvas.context.textAling = 'center';
    canvas.context.fillText(member.user.tag.toUpperCase(), 512, 410)
    canvas.context.font = '32px OpenSans-Bold';
    canvas.context.fillText(Você é o ${member.guild.memberCount} Tenno em nosso servidor, 512, 455)
    canvas.context.beginPath()
    canvas.context.arc(512, 166, 119, 0, Math.PI * 2, true)
    canvas.context.closePath()
    canvas.context.clip()
    await Canvas.loadImage(member.user.displayAvatarURL({format: 'png', size: 1024}))
        .then(img => {
            canvas.context.drawImage(img, 393, 47, 238, 238);
           })
    let atta = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.create.toBuffer(), Bem vindo ${member.id}.png)
    try {
        welcomechannel.send(Olá Tenno ${member}, bem vindo ao ${member.guild.name}!, atta)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
});
```